# std::ifstream data type?

Tags: c++, csv, ifstream

The variable "read" in this program needs to be passed through a function and i don't know what data type it is. I have used http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/
and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ but I'm struggling to find anything, is this just not possible?

```
int main()
{
string line = " ", ans = " ", ans2 = " ", data = " ";
int i = 0, j = 0;
cout << "What file do you want to read? : ";
cin >> ans;
cout << "What do you want the new file to be called? : ";
cin >> ans2;
ifstream read(ans.c_str());
for (i = 0; !read.eof(); i++)
{
    read_function(line, read);
    write_function(line, ans2);
}
return 0;
}


string read_function(string line, string read)
{
        getline(read, line, ' ');
        cout << line;
}

void write_function(string line, string ans2)
{
    ofstream write(ans2.c_str(), ios::app);
    write << line;
    write.close();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "struggling to find anything"? It literally says right there that the object `read` is of type `ifstream`, and you just linked to reference for _ifstream_. What is the problem?

Comment: I need to pass the variable read through a function and i don't know what data type it is

Comment: It says right there. Is this a troll? @doctorlove no it doesn't

Comment: `read` look slike a function definiton not a variable - is there more context to theis code and a specific error.

Comment: @doctorlove {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>

Comment: If you have a build error, present your [MCVE].

Comment: There's clearly some extra context to reproduce the error message - mention the rest of the code and the error in your question and we may be able to help

Comment: @doctorlove Post has been updated

Comment: That is not a [MCVE]. Still, it's enough to see that you're passing an `ifstream` to a function that expects a `string`. I don't know why you thought that would work.

Comment: Furthermore, the loop condition `!read.eof()` is wrong. Which book are you using to learn C++? It's bad.

Comment: C++ Programming in easy steps - mike mcgrath

Comment: Never heard of it; don't know why it's so highly rated on Amazon. Here's [our list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I have a working copy of this code where the for loop is inside the read function but my "boss" needs it to be in *int(main)*

Comment: `ifstream read(ans.c_str());` tells you that `read` is of type `ifstream`. What more do you need to know?

Comment: This code is for a company? Your boss accepts code like this?

Comment: I am on work experience, And you are just a toxic person.

Answer (score 3):

You have `ifstream read` but a function

```
string read_function(string line, string read)
                                 // ^------
```

If you change the function to

```
 string read_function(string line, ifstream & read)
                                 // ^------
```

the `read_function` then expects a stream as the second parameter, not a string.

You will have a similar problem with the next function.

The comments point out other problems.

If you get an error about types, sit back and look at what you are passing to functions and what they expect.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what i needed to know, Sorry to everyone else i am just starting to use c++ so my question might've seemed odd to you. :)

Comment: Glad to have helped. Keep practising. Keep asking questions. Find one or two good books (look at the list in the comments). Ask you boss/work mates too.